# Embeddable FileSystem?

Tags: c#, c++, filesystems, storage, binaryfiles

Do you know some library/framework/embeddedEngine for storing data in one binary file? Something like file system in one file. It also must support tools for fragmentating data after removing/updating. Prefer languages C++ or C#. Platform Windows.

Thank you for any advice!!!

Comment: Did you mean *defragmenting* data? And is there any reason why a compressed file (like a ZIP) won't work for you? Even Microsoft has recently abandoned the "mini file system in a file" concept with later versions of Office.

Comment: @Cody: "Defragmenting" doesn't make sense in that sense. I think he means that he needs to be able to insert data in the middle of the file without writing the entire file out to disk afterward.

Comment: @Billy: Yes you right. I want to insert data, remove data and avoid defragmentation;)

Comment: @Cody ZIP is terribly inefficient cause any update to it requires rewriting the whole archive. Also, you are wrong regarding the motives behind Microsoft's change of format. There was an Open Document Format gaining popularity, and Microsoft had to offer it's own proprietary alternative in order to hold the market. They needed to have this format as XML-based (similar to ODF) in order to compete with ODF.

Comment: fragmentation will appear one way or another cause writing is not sequential. However virtual file system will handle this problem to most extent. Fragmentation by itself is not a huge problem. It's an inefficient use of empty space (gaps) that is, and virtual file systems handle this fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESENT, [you can check out my framework](http://esentserialize.codeplex.com/) for C#.

Unlike SQLite, it's OK to hold 1GB of data in a single field.

Comment: Err... *why* would you want to store 1GB of data in a single field? (Not ripping on the library; just seems like a 1GB binary blob has other problems than not being handled by most serialization libraries) Seems like a solution in search of a problem. (But I did +1 simply because it's another solution here)

Comment: @"Billy ONeal", "you can" doesn't mean "you should". We both know nothing about the Edward's problem: maybe he needs to handle the terabyte-sized dataset produced by his space telescope? Or maybe he needs a storage to replicate all the data stored on his windows partition? ESENT is just more versatile then SQLite. Besides, not everyone needs an SQL engine: SQL=additional overhead and complexity.

Comment: @Soonts: Fair enough. OTOH, I don't think "embeddable" would be a requirement if he was handling such datasets. Though I don't see how SQL == additional overhead and complexity.

Comment: @Soonts: As per http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html , it's okay to store 1GB in a single SQLite field too. (The default limit is 1 billion bytes, but that can be changed by the user setting a `#define`, up to a maximum of the maximum size of a 32 bit integer, which incidentally is the same limit as ESENT)

Comment: @"Billy ONeal", I've implemented a file system on the top of my ESENT framework (see the same link for its source code). The space overhead is about 10%, the read speed is great, the write speed is still adequate.By "overhead" I meant e.g. time to parse the SQL grammar (and for non-embeddable SQL servers - IPC or network latency). By "complexity" I meant e.g. key constraints, stored procedures and query optimization.

Comment: ESENT looks like interesting;) I'll check it;) Thank you all guys! Your advices are very important for me;) +1 for all;)

Answer (score 4):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) isn't exactly a filesystem, but it does do what you ask in that it is embeddable, and has any tool you could want (given that it is, of course, SQL). Plus all the code is public domain so you can use it for pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Really.

Answer (score 1):

Check our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/). This is the virtual file system, written in C (with JNI binding for Java) and usable on most modern platforms including Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On which platform? On Linux you can use a virtual file system.

Comment: "Platform Windows", from question text. C# tag is another clue.